# How to get all combinations of a set of numbers that will add up to or only slightly beyond a set number?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, methods, sum

I'm trying to create a method that will take a list of integers and return a list of integer arrays containing all combinations of numbers that sum up to the target.

For example if the target was 5 and the input list had

```
List<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3}
```

The result would be

```
List<int[]> resultNumbers = {[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2], [1,2,2], [1,1,3], [2,3]} etc.
```

I was writing this method for an app I'm making, but then moved the code to a console app so I could focus on it alone. I'd also like to add tolerances for how close the numbers can be to the target and count as a set of numbers that add to the target.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
List<int> multipliers = new List<int>();
List<int[]> resultNumbers = new List<int[]>();
List<int> toFindAllSums = new List<int>();
List<int> toFindAllmultipliers = new List<int>();
List<int> toFindAllnumbers = new List<int>();
Random random = new Random();
int max = random.Next(20);
int target = 2000;

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    int d = random.Next(200, 400);
    numbers.Add(d);
}

foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int iterations = 0;
    while (sum< 2000)
    {
        sum += i;
        iterations += 1;
        Console.Write(i + " + ");
        if (sum > 2000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" = " + sum);
            Console.Write("\n\t "+ iterations + "\n");
            multipliers.Add(iterations);
        }
    }
}

foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    int[] temp = new int[multipliers.ElementAt(numbers.IndexOf(i))];
    for (int j = 0; j < multipliers.ElementAt(numbers.IndexOf(i));  j++ )
    {
        temp[j] = i;
        toFindAllSums.Add(temp.Sum());
        toFindAllmultipliers.Add(j+1);
        toFindAllnumbers.Add(i);
    }
    resultNumbers.Add(temp);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This is what I have updated since this question began, I do get quite a few results from it but I'm not sure if it is giving me all the possible results.

```
public List<int[]> FindAllSums(List<int> numbers, int target)
    {
        List<int> multipliers = new List<int>();
        List<int[]> resultNumbers = new List<int[]>();

        // find the maximum number of times a number int he given list can go into
        //the target and either equal or ecceed it (this could probably have been done using division)
        foreach (int i in numbers)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int iterations = 0;
            while (sum < 2000)
            {
                sum += i;
                iterations += 1;
                if (sum > 2000)
                {
                    multipliers.Add(iterations);
                }
            }
        }

        //add those posibilites to the list of results.
        foreach (int i in numbers)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[multipliers.ElementAt(numbers.IndexOf(i))];
            for (int j = 0; j < multipliers.ElementAt(numbers.IndexOf(i)); j++)
            {
                temp[j] = i;
            }
            resultNumbers.Add(temp);
        }

        //since we know the maximum number of times each given number can go into the 
        //target we start creating arrays of numbers that will add to the target
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count(); i++)
        {
            //create list because I like lists more than arrays
            List<int> tempList = new List<int>();

            //for all elements in the input list
            for (int k = 0; k < multipliers.ElementAt(i); k++)
            {
                //for the number of times the given number can go into the target
                for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numbers.Count(); j1++)
                {
                    //add that number to the list 
                    tempList.Add(numbers.ElementAt(i));
                    for (int j2 = 0; j2 < j1; j2++)
                    {
                        tempList.Add(numbers.ElementAt(i));

                    }                        
                    for (int j = j1; j < numbers.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        if (tempList.Sum() > 2000)
                        {
                            resultNumbers.Add(tempList.ToArray());
                            tempList.Clear();
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tempList.Add(numbers.ElementAt(j));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: Think about how would a human do it. Then see if you can implement the same steps in an algorithm. Then write code. Tip: I would start by sorting the input list in a descending order and start from the biggest input. You might also want to use recursion here.

Comment: Why isn't [1,1,2,2]  in your example output?  [1,1,1,1,2,2]?  What about 1000 1s?

Comment: 1000 1s wouldn't equal to 5.

Comment: Can the `target` be negative? Can entries in `numbers` be negative? What should occur if the target is **lower** than any value in `numbers`?

Comment: No, the target won't be negative and shouldn't allow for negative targets, but I'm more concerned about getting the thing to work as it is, I don't care about negative numbers right now and can simply fix that issue by making the input target a uint, there will be no negative numbers for what I'm using this method for.  And the use case I have for this the input numbers will always be under the target. but if they are over I guess they would just go into the target once.

Comment: Oh, so instead of "beyond a set number" like it says in the title, you need the result to be equal to the number?

Comment: like if you had a list of numbers {19, 34, 21} and the target was 100. a few of the results would be {19,19,19,19,19,19} and {21,21,21,21,21}  once the sum of the set of numbers is beyond 100 it shouldn't add more numbers to the set.

Comment: So if the target was 100 then {49,50,100} would be a valid solution? {49, 50, 50}?

Comment: I guess, I just want it close because I don't know if any set out of a given list of numbers would add up to a given target, so there needs to be some tolerance for that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code, then Visaul studio sent me "IndexOutofBoundsException", 
i didn't understand very well your code, but i guess your idea of implementation maybe is not correct.

This problem is not a problem of Dynamic Programming.

Let Cn be the result with the target number n, if n = 5, and input list is {1, 2, 3}, we can have the fellow equation :

```
C5 = C1 x C4 + C2 x C3 + C3 x C2   (1)
```

If n = 6, the equation will be:

```
C6 = C1 x C5 + C2 x C4 + C3 x C3   (2)
```

Here "x" acts like cross product, for example, we can calculate C1 and C2 easily:

```
C1 = {{1}}
```

```
C2 = {{1, 1}, {2}}
```

Thus

```
C1 x C2 = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2}}
```

And "+" means union, for example:

```
C2 x C3 + C3 x C2 = C2 x C3
```

Because C2 x C3 = C3 X C2

For the implementation, we can create a class overriding operators "x" and "+":

```
class Combination 
{
     List<List<int>> combination;

     public override bool Equals(Object obj) {...};

     public Combination operator* (Combination c1, Combination c2) {...};

     public Combination operator+ (Combination c1, Combination c2) {...};
}
```

Notice that in equation (1) contains repeat combinations C2 and C3, to speed the program, we can use a hashset to save all calculated combination (like a closed list):

```
HashSet<Combination> calculatedCombinations = new HashSet<Combination>(){};
```

Now we should do another trick, notice that:

```
C2 = {{1, 1}, {2}}   (3)
```

But it can be written as:

```
C2 = {{2}, {1, 1}}   (4)
```

So when we override Equals(), something must be done to handle (3) and (4), my opinion is to convert C2 to a flat and ordered array, create a auxiliary function:

```
private int[] convertCombination(Combination c) {...};
```

then convertCombination(C2) = {1, 1, 2} which is a unic form, so insides Equals() can use this function to campare objects. Hope this is helpful to you.

Att: If the input list has a number which is greater than the target number, then this number should be ignored while traversing the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic programming to solve problems looks that way, it depends on trying every thing (all possible ways) of answers but with limitation to avoid time limit exceed.
in this problem you can use DP(Dynamic programming) by 2D.
you can see [Dynamic Programming](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/tutorial/)!